# Send specific push notification messages to different users in a single request to GCM

Tags: android, ios, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging, apple-push-notifications

i want to know how we can send multiple user's specific push notifications messages in a row.

For example using GCM, if you want to send a specific message to a specific user you can use this content in your POST request to Google servers

```
    {
      "to" : "user_registration_id",
      "priority" : "normal",
      "notification" : {
        "body" : "You have 3 messages in your inbox",
        "title" : "NewsMagazine.com",
        "icon" : "new",
      }
    }
```

The problem that i'am facing right now, is that i have tons of notifications to send at a time, each notification is user specific, so i have to make multiple POST requests in a row to Google servers to send each notification separately, and this cause a huge performance issue on my server. What i want is to be able to send them in a single POST request

Any idea on how this might be implemented ?

Thank you.

Comment: Any reason why you aren't using Firebase push notification instead ?

Comment: Well Firebase has been introduced recently, and i'm working with a slightly old application so i try to optimise the existing server code. Is this problem can be solved with Fierbase ?

Comment: Yea, and thats why you have no answers

Comment: i'll check Fierbase, but i imagine that this problem has been already faced with GCM, many applications send specific push for users (ie :Facebook) so there is certainly some  approaches to optimize the server code and requests number.

Comment: I checked FireBase documentation, and i don't see any new parameters that can help me https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref#send-downstream